# Clip labels to the extent of another data frame

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcmap, labeling, data-frame

[image]

I'm making a townwide map of a water distribution system with a zoomed in inset (a seperate data frame) for the densest part of town. For the townwide map, I'd like to show the labels for pipe size and diameter everywhere except within the bounds of the inset, as that information is redundant and clutters the townwide map.

The red line on the town map shows the extent of the inset data frame. Is there a way that I can clip or hide labels within the bounds of the extent of the inset data frame?

Comment: The only way I can think of to do that would be to use a subset of the layer e.g. a selection of just the features you want. You could have the same symbology on the full layer underneath with no labels. Or you could convert to annotation and get rid of the ones you don't want.

Answer (score 1):

Not the most elegant solution, but it should work.

Create a polygon layer and add to your main data frame.  Symbolise with no fill and no border.

[image]

Create a new polygon that aligns with your inset extent frame

[image]

Turn on the *Maplex* label engine, open the label properties for your new layer, and for Conflict Detection set your feature interior and border weight to 1000

[image]

Now no labels will draw over your new polygon

[image]

Comment: And make sure you don't check Never Remove on the pipes layer :-)